# MySQL Select IN with NodeJs detect empty fields

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm pretty new to `nodejs` in gernal and im facing a problem with `mysql` selects. 
So, lets say i have a array of ids and i want to select them from my MySQL Database like:

```
Con.query('SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Id IN (1,2,3,4)' , function (err,
results, fields) { results contains: 1,2,3 because 4 dont exists in DB }
```

So i would receive the data for Rows with ID 1,2,3 but not for ID 4 because it dont exists. I wonder how i can detect, that ID 4 dont exist.

Is there a way to retrieve all the Ids i asked for in the query Function or kind of an option which i can enable to receive NULL for the given id if it dont exists like:

```
ID 1: Data
ID 2: Data
ID 3: Data
ID 4: null - because dont exists
```

If there is no way to solve this with IN Statement, can i simply make 4 single 
Selects with explicit ID ( because i will receive 0 if the data dont exists ) or will it overload MySQL if i have like 1000 Selects in like 1 minute?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In the future, you don't need to explain that you are new to something, just ask the question. Also, there's no need to thank people in your question. Consider phrasing your question in a way that can apply to others, for example: do not use the word 'I' except when explaining what you have tried to do to resolve the problem yourself. Please also consider proofreading for capitalization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check it via loop, if you put ID in array;

```
var ids = [1,2,3,4]
Con.query('SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Id IN (1,2,3,4)' , function (err, results, fields) { 
for(var i = 0;i<ids.length;i++){
 if(ids.indexOf(fields[i]['id'])>-1){
 console.log(" found ID = "+ids[i])
 }else{
 console.log(" ID NOT FOUND = "+ids[i])
 }
}
```

});

Comment: Nevermind ... i just mixed this. with Variable. in the wrong way and thereforce i was not able to access the array i defined above... Thanks!

Comment: scope of ids will be inside you async function , but the scope of fields will not be outside the async